# ggplot: plot frequency counts of values in a dataframe (with no preprocessing)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I often find myself doing this:

```
# Original data
df.test <- data.frame(value=floor(rexp(10000, 1/2)))

# Compute the frequency of every value
# or the probability
freqs <- tabulate(df.test$value)
probs <- freqs / sum(freqs)

# Create a new dataframe with the frequencies (or probabilities)
df.freqs <- data.frame(n=1:length(freqs), freq=freqs, probs=probs) 

# Plot them, usually in log-log
g <- ggplot(df.freqs, aes(x=n, y = freq)) + geom_point() + 
  scale_y_log10() + scale_x_log10()
plot(g)
```

[image]

Can it be done just using `ggplot` without creating an intermediate dataset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For frequency count, you can specify the `stat` parameter in `geom_point` as `count`:

```
ggplot(df.test, aes(x = value)) + geom_point(stat = "count") + 
    scale_x_log10() + scale_y_log10()
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks! What about normalized frequencies (probability) ?

Comment: There might be a better solution using `stat_summary`, but I just find it much easier to prepare data before hand. Something like: `ggplot(data.frame(prop.table(table(df.test))), aes(x = df.test, y = Freq)) + geom_point()`.